# My "Grand Total" output will not stay right-aligned with other outputs

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double loan_Payment;
    double insurance;
    double gas;
    double oil;
    double tires;
    double maintenance;


    /// text setup 
    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "Loan Payment";

    std::cout.width(15); std::cin >> std::right >> loan_Payment;



    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "Insurance";

    std::cout.width(15); std::cin >> std::right >> insurance;



    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "Gas";

    std::cout.width(15); std::cin >> std::right >> gas;



    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "Oil";

    std::cout.width(15); std::cin >> std::right >> oil;



    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "Tires";

    std::cout.width(15); std::cin >> std::right >> tires;



    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "Maintenance" ;

    std::cout.width(15); std::cin >> std::right >> maintenance;



    // adding total.yearly total, 10%

    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "Total";

    std::cout.width(15); std::cout << (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance) << right << endl;

    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "Yearly Total";

    std::cout.width(15); std::cout << (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance)) << right << endl;

    std::cout.width(30); std::cout << std::left << "10%";

    std::cout.width(15); std::cout << (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance))*.10 << right << endl;
    //if yearly total is greater than 1000 add 10 percent of the yearly total
    double yearly_total;
    yearly_total = (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance));
    if (yearly_total >= 1000)

        std::cout.width(30); std::cout << "Grand Total" << left;

    std::cout.width(60); std::cout << ((12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance))*.10) + (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance)) << right << endl;







}
```

Write a C++ program that asks the user to enter the monthly costs for the following expenses incurred from operating your automobile: loan payment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, and maintenance. The program should then display the total monthly cost of these expenses, and a projected total annual cost of these expenses.

Label each cost.  The labels should be left aligned and have a column width of 30 characters.  The cost should be aligned right and displayed with two decimal places with a column width of 15.

If the yearly total is greater than 1000 dollars, add 10 percent of the yearly total to the yearly total.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `std::cin >> std::right >> loan_Payment;`?

Comment: There are extra `std::cout.width(15)`s all over the place that don't do anything because you change the width again before using `std::cout`.

Comment: question aligned left then cin input answer aligned right.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'm not sure why `std::right` is even legal for input when things like `std::fill` aren't, but it seems it's a no-op.

Comment: @chris Yeah.  Pretty sure it is just a non op.  I have no idea if you can even specify the width and alignment of input.  I do not think you can do it in standard C++.  There might be a library like ncruses that is able to.

Comment: I am only having problem with the last line

Comment: @NathanOliver, You can definitely specify width to take only the next N characters, but cppreference says alignment does nothing despite actually compiling.

Answer (score 1):

The last line

```
std::cout << ((12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance))*.10)
              + (12 * (loan_Payment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance)) 
         << right << endl;
```

Has the output first and `right` afterwards. Naturally, the alignment will not have any effects on what is already displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your help.